# Would the Anglican church accommodate credo baptists?

Tags: doctrine

Is it an our-way-or-the-highway case when it comes to doctrine issues like these or can you discuss it with the local priest?

I really could never have a child of mine baptised unless it is something he/she chose to do.

Belief must precede baptism and a baby cannot believe afterall.

Comment: "Belief must precede baptism". That's a very definite statement of faith which contradicts the Anglican faith. You're almost certainly welcome to discuss it, but I expect that "discussion" would take the form of trying to convince you that you're wrong. If you have such a strong disagreement, perhaps you should look for a church whose beliefs are more in line with yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a credo-baptist but was elected even to the level of warden at my old Anglican church. In my experience there aren't structural barriers that would prevent a credo-baptist from being an involved member of an Anglican church, though some individual Anglican churches may expect their leaders to be more on the same theological page than that. And each country's Anglican denomination has different rules, so it's possible that there may be more structural barriers in place in Anglican churches near you.

In general you shouldn't face any opposition to discussing different views on baptism (though there are more and less appropriate times to do so; don't argue about infant baptism in the middle of an infant baptism of someone else's child!) Protestants consider baptism to be a secondary issue and so different beliefs about baptism don't make you a heretic like different views about God or the Gospel might, though a credo-baptist won't be able to be ordained in a paedo-baptist denomination and vice versa. And the doctrine of *sola scriptura* places a high importance on each individual being personally convinced by arguments from scripture, so questioning and debating these issues is encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "our-way-or-the highway". Lay Anglicans are not required to accept all aspects of church doctrine as a condition of membership.

If a member becomes a parent, infant baptism becomes a question of practice, rather than doctrine. Here again, though, refusal to have your child baptised would not lead to expulsion.

Most priests would be very happy to discuss it as a  matter of doctrine, and might insist on discussing it if it becomes a question of practice (i.e.if you have a baby). They will be able to recommend books or other resources that may or may not convince you.

But you will not be expelled.